# Levi Civita symbols of matrix elements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

The Levi Civita symbol($\epsilon$)  is +1 when the object is an even permutation of the reference object, and -1 if it's an odd permutation.

> How do I assign the Levi-Civita symbol for a matrix element?

I noticed that it just equal to the column number minus the row number in case of a $2$ by $2$ matrix but I wonder if there's a better way to think about it. Please explain in your answer, how even and odd permutations have anything to do with this.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by *matrix element*? Are you referring to the sparse matrix $E_{ij}$ of all zeros except for a $1$ in entry $(i,j)$?

Comment: @SammyBlack I am referring to a $n$ by $n$ matrix with elements $a_{ijk ...n}$